# Can I put 1998 LS400 wheels on a 2013 RAV4?

Tags: toyota, tires, wheels, lexus

LS400 has 225/60R16 wheels.

RAV4 has 235/55R18 wheels.

Can I move the wheels off the LS400 to the RAV4? The bolt patterns and center bores are identical.

https://www.wheel-size.com/size/toyota/rav4/2013/

https://www.wheel-size.com/size/lexus/ls/1998/

Answer (score 1):

Based on the link information, the one piece of important data that is missing is the ET figure, also known as rim offset. According to those charts, the ET45 figure is the same for both rims.

If you are comfortable with fender clearance, which is likely considering it's an SUV, you should have no complications with moving the LS400 wheels to the Rav4.

If the LS400 rims are heavier weight, you may notice a difference in handling and suspension.

Comment: I probably shouldn't turn on AWD with the LS wheels on right?

Comment: I'm not sure what aspect of the LS wheels would preclude AWD. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I read that running different size tires is bad for the AWD system, is that right?

Comment: @Dissenter: I think that goes for different sizes on the front and back. You are planning to swap all 4 wheels, are you?

Comment: Also take into account that the diameter of the "new" wheels is smaller, this will lead to a speedo reading 6% too high.

Answer (score 0):

You should test fit and see if there is still enough clearance and that noting scrapes when you go over bumps.

Apparently the minimum rim size the 2013 RAV4 was sold with was 17" so you could get into trouble with clearance from the Brake calipers!

The new tires are also smaller on the outside, 4 cm in diameter, so your car will ride 2 cm lower.
Also, your car will show a ~6% higher driving speed than before. 
You can use one of these online-calculators to see if there is a better fit tire to minimize the difference. [Like this on](https://tiresize.com/calculator/)

Also be aware that in some jurisdictions you need to have a technical inspection or certificate for the rim and car that you want to combine.

Comment: Its the other way around, the original 18" wheels are going to be exchanged for 16". The diameter of the new wheels is smaller, leading the speedometer to read 6% too fast (so 100km/h will actually be 94km/h)